# How to add the output of a php-function to a list

Tags: php

So i am trying to write code to do the following very basic thing:

*Take a number from the html input-form

*Take a counter, going from 0 to the input-number in a loop

*get the number as a list-item in the php-output, except if it is divisible by 3 or 5, which get ping and pong respectively as an output-value.

At the moment, this sadly does not work and all i get displayed is the tite & an error-message.
Any and all help is very much appreciated!

---

Here the code from the html input-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>PHP Ping Pong Purified Perfection!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Geimme a number between 0 and 100 or you get a paddlin´!</h1>
        <form action="phpPingPong.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputNumber">The Number:</label>
                <input id="inputNumber" name="inputNumber" class="form-control" type="number">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Gimme the darn result already!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here´s the code from the php-page:

```
<?php 
    $inputNumber = $_GET["inputNumber"];
    $counter = 0;
    $outputMessage = "";

    function colorFate($inputNumber, $outputMessage)
    {
        if ($inputNumber < 100){

            for ( $counter == 1; $counter <= $inputNumber; $counter ++) {

                if ($counter % 5 === 0 && $counter % 3 === 0){
                    $outputMessage = "Ping-Pong";
                }

                else if ($counter % 3 === 0){
                    $outputMessage = "Ping";
                }

                else if ($counter % 5 === 0){
                    $outputMessage = "Pong";
                }

                else if ($counter % 5 != 0){
                    $outputMessage = $counter;
                }

                $outputMessage = "<li>"+ $outputMessage +"</li>";

                "#outputList".append ($outputMessage) ;


            }   
        }
        else{
            alert("Please follow the guidelines on what to enter!");
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> PHPingPong </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Read and Weep!</h1>
    <ul id="outputList">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks again!

Comment: PHP 101: `+` is for mathematical addition. `.`. is for concatenation. `$x = 'a' + 'b'` is going to end up being `0`. and you php code seem to be mixed in with javascript, which is utterly illegal syntax.

Comment: Helpful hint: You say you are getting an error message - show us what it is!

Comment: @lolcat please up-vote the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The First problem:-** form method is `POST` and you use `$_GET` to retrieve the value in second page. change code like below:-

`$inputNumber = $_GET["inputNumber"];` to  `$inputNumber = $_POST["inputNumber"];`

**Second one is :-**  `$outputMessage = "<li>"+ $outputMessage +"</li>";` must be `$outputMessage = "<li>".$outputMessage."</li>";`

**Third is :-** `"#outputList".append ($outputMessage) ;` it seems that you are mixing javascript code to php code. Don't do that.

So your second page code must be like below:-

```
      <?php 
    $inputNumber = $_POST["inputNumber"];
    

    function colorFate($inputNumber)
    {
        
        $new_array = array();
        $outputMessage = "";
        if ($inputNumber < 100){

            for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= $inputNumber; $counter++) {

                if ($counter % 5 === 0 && $counter % 3 === 0){
                    $new_array['Ping-Pong'][$counter] = $counter;
                }else if ($counter % 3 === 0){
                    $new_array['Ping'][$counter] = $counter;
                }else if ($counter % 5 === 0){
                    $new_array['Pong'][$counter] = $counter;
                }else if ($counter % 5 != 0){
                    $new_array['nothing'][$counter] = $counter;
                }
            }
            return $new_array;  
        }
        else{
            alert("Please follow the guidelines on what to enter!");
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> PHPingPong </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Read and Weep!</h1>
    <?php $result = colorFate($inputNumber);?>
    <?php foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        echo "<ul><span>$key numbers are:-".implode(',',$value)."</ul>";
    }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My poor attempt at adding items to the list was indeed cannibalized from a similar javascript project. How can i still use a list-structure in php?

Comment: can you tell what outcome you want if number is given 10, because i added that and based on your condition it gives correct value `PongPong`. Or you tell any outcome with any number.

Comment: i did so & thanks very much for the input.
At the moment, my output for an input-number of 50 is only "PongPong" however. Not quite there yet, but almost... :)
The intended output would be 1 2 ping 3 4 pong 6 7 8 ping pong 11 ping 13 14 pingpong .....

Comment: That´s perfect, thank you!!!   Do you have any idea what would be a simple php-project i could try to improve on my current skill-level?

Comment: If the code works for you then please mark it as an answer. Also `W3school`,`php.net`, `google` will help you in improving your php skill.Thanks.